# Eclipse: how to enable compile options, build error in C++, OpenCL program

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, compiler-errors, opencl

I get this error when I build C++, OpenCl program by Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options. SNM     line 32, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h   C/C++ Problem
```

I can successfully compile it by terminal($g++...)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project on *Project Explorer* -> *Properties* -> *C/C++ Build* -> *Settings*.

In the *Tools settings* tab, there is a *GCC C++ Compiler* item. Expand it and select *Settings* -> *Miscesllaneous*.

Append at the end of the *Other Flags* text input the string `-std=c++11`

This should be done for any *configuration* you need.

Comment: Thanks alot @Paolo M, But after I did that I get a lot of errors (25 errors) about OpenCL instruction like:
Description Resource Path Location Type
undefined reference to `clCreateBuffer' SNM.cpp /SNM/src line 176 C/C++ Problem

Answer (score 0):

add -opencl to the flags. Project Explorer -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> compiler that you are using -> miscellaneous.